# Creating a numpy arange from min and max values of a pandas dframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i wanted to create a numpy arange with min and max values from a pandas series, but since the min and max values are Series objects numpy is giving out the value error

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

This is what im trying

```
minx = np.min(x_test)
maxx = np.max(x_test)

np.arange(minx,maxx,0.1)
```

Kindly help

Comment: works for me on a series, can you post `x_test`

Comment: both `np.min` and the pandas `Series.min` return a scalar and not a Series, so this error is not reproducable right now. Can you post example data and expected output.

Comment: @Datanovice I am guessing the input is a dataframe , not a series.

Comment: Yes `x_test` is a single column dataframe. I converted it to a series by `x_test.iloc[:,0]`

Answer (score 0):

Since `x_test` is a dataframe I would need to convert it to a series to get a scalar min value. Hence this should work

```
minx = np.min(x_test.iloc[:,0])
maxx = np.max(x_test.iloc[:,0])
np.arange(minx,maxx,0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also get the values from the dataframe as

```
minx = np.min(df).values[0]
maxx = np.max(df).values[0]

np.arange(minx,maxx,0.1)
```

Test Data:

```
   A
0  0
1  0
2  2
3  4
4  3
```

Result:

```
[0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7
 1.8 1.9 2.  2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 3.  3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5
 3.6 3.7 3.8 3.9]
```